# Color postscript in IDL

Tags: colors, postscript, idl-programming-language

I've got some plots that I want to output as postscript files using IDL.

I have used the following:

```
SET_PLOT, 'PS' 
DEVICE, FILENAME = 'myplot.ps', /LANDSCAPE
PLOT, ...
DEVICE, /CLOSE
```

But this outputs in black and white only.  How can I color postscript files?

Answer (score 2):

Add /COLOR to your DEVICE call.